# Unable to connect to local host after modifying Apache config file (Windows)

Tags: windows, apache, localhost, configuration-files, httpserver

I have downloaded the Apache HTTP server for windows and installed it. I have created a test html file under `C:/mobileTraining/core/workspace/TestProject`
I then added a permissions directory tag in the `httpd.conf` file, so that it now looks like the following:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory C:/mobileTraining/core/workspace>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /TestProject C:/mobileTraining/core/workspace/TestProject
```

I've tried this with and without the first `Directory` tag, which was there already.

When I then save these changes and go to `http://localhost/TestProject/TestPage.html` in my browser (I've tried Firefox and Chrome), I get a connection error. This is from Chrome:

```
This webpage is not available
Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Is there something blindingly obvious in my set-up that I've missed?

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart your services?

Comment: I had a look in my Apache Services monitor and there were no services to restart. How is this normally done?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access your site by including the port the default setup for this is 8080

```
http://localhost:8080/TestProject/TestPage.html
```

Comment: I tried the link you suggested and it didn't work. How would I check that 8080 is the same port number I have? Thanks.

Comment: You will be able to find in the server.xml file in conf directory where you have installed Tomcat  ...\Tomcat 7.0\conf\server.xml. look for a tag as follows <Connector port="8080"

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are able to access `http://localhost/`

Also, i suppose you have `TestPage.html` in `C:/mobileTraining/core/workspace/TestProject` 
You are setting permissions for `C:/mobileTraining/core/workspace` ?

As mentioned in [Example here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) . Try below.

```
Alias /TestProject "C:/mobileTraining/core/workspace/TestProject"

<Directory "C:/mobileTraining/core/workspace/TestProject">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks slash. I cannot access localhost either, which I assume is the main problem. Do you have any other steps I should take to resolve this?I have the TestPage.html is that folder yes. what do you mean exactly by setting permissions for that directory? Is that not what we're doing with the Directory tags?

Comment: You have `TestPage.html` in directory `TestProject` and you are setting permissions for `workspace` in directory tags. Never tried this so not sure if it works. Notice how Alias and Directory is used in example link. Run `httpd -t` command to look for any syntax error in conf files. Also, check your `error.log` for any specific errors. Consider up voting if it helped.